# передать в функцию аргументы из элементов списка

Tags: python

```
import webbrowser

def wb(url):
    webbrowser.open(url)

list_urls = ['https://vk.com', 'https://yandex.com', 'http://google.com']

wb(list_urls)
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так:

```
import webbrowser

def wb(list_urls):
    for url in list_urls:
        webbrowser.open(url)

list_urls = ['https://vk.com', 'https://yandex.com', 'http://google.com']
wb(list_urls)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import webbrowser

def wb(url):
    webbrowser.open(url)

list_urls = ['https://vk.com', 'https://yandex.com', 'http://google.com']

for _ in map(wb, list_urls):
    pass
```